# Can't mock imported function in ESM Modules mocha

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocking, mocha.js, es6-modules

So I've been trying to mock an imported function for a file that uses external calls to DB, redis, and etc. So I can isolate only the methods of a class that uses that function.

In production we are using Node v14, assume that there is no way to update the version of the application.

So what I need to do for example:

```
// Imported function
export const functionToBeReplaced = () => {};


// Class that I am trying to write unit tests for
import {functionToBeReplaced} from 'a/long/path/to/function';

Class A {

   testMethod(...args) {
       // Some business logic to test
       
       // result of method should be passed here
       functionToBeReplaced(result);
       // Some other business logic
       return someOtherResult;
   }
}
```

I've tried using libraries such as [esmock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esmock), but because we are using the version of NodeJS 14, it throws errors

```
export const mockedClass = await esmock('a/path/to/class', {
  'a/long/path/to/function': {
    functionToBeReplaced() {
    },
  },
}, {});


The requested module 'node:module' does not provide an export named 'isBuiltin'
```

It seems the only fix for that is to bump NodeJS version to 16, but due to some other errors we can't just upgrade the version

Also I've tried using libraries such as [proxyquire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/proxyquire) but because we've specified in package.json `type: module` proxyquire doesn't really want to work with ESM

We are using mocha as test framework with these launch options

```
mocha --config=./.mocharc-dev.json --exit --es-module-specifier-resolution=node --experimental-modules src/**/*.test.js
```

// .mocharc-dev.json

```
{
  "diff": true,
  "extension": [
    "js"
  ],
  "package": "./package.json",
  "slow": 75,
  "timeout": 20000,
  "ui": "bdd",
  "recursive": true,
  "exit": true,
  "env" : "dotenv_config_path=./.dev-env",
  "require": "dotenv/config"
}
```

Is there any other way to mock imported functions in ESM modules using NodeJS v14 and mocha?

Comment: So the solution to this problem was just downgrading esmock version to <2.0.0